# Cadence Virtuoso Schematic: Input pin goes to 2 different nets

Tags: circuit-design, cadence, schematic, virtuoso

I have a silly problem regarding input pins connecting to 2 different nets of a circuit in cadence virtuoso. Due to non-sharable agreement, I cannot share the actual circuit. But I can provide simple block diagram. This is the following non-overlapping clock circuit. I am concerned with 4 input pins which selects the nets in the diagram and select the specific MUX. The idea is when externally ***I0*** input pin is selected then circuit should select both ***I0_M1*** of MUX 1 and also ***I0_M2*** of MUX 2, ***I1*** input pin is selected then circuit should select both ***I1_M1*** of MUX 1 and also ***I1_M2*** of MUX 2 and so on.

As, the internal circuit cannot be changed. I cannot connect ***I0*** pin to both ***I0_M1*** and ***I0_M2***, ***I1*** pin to both ***I1_M1*** and ***I1_M2*** and so on because in that case ***I0_M1*** and ***I0_M2*** are connected or ***I1_M1*** and ***I1_M2*** will be connected.

If the bottom part with mux 2 and feedback part would not be there, it would not be a problem. there are 4 buffers for different delays. So 4 selectable inputs (***I0-I3***) select the output from 4 buffers and feeds to the 4 inputs of the MUX. ***I0_M1 - I3_M1*** and ***I0_M2 - I3_M2*** are for inputs of the corresponding MUXs. ***I0_M1 - I3_M1*** are net names. Suppose, when I connect ***I0*** pin to ***I0_M1*** and ***I0_M2***, in the schematic editors those are shorted as those have 2 net names connected to 1 pin

Now I have implemented the circuit in Cadence virtuoso. Now stuck with the following problem. How can I implement the connection suppose when ***I0*** input pin is selected then circuit should select both ***I0_M1*** of MUX 1 and also ***I0_M2*** of MUX 2? Do I need extra circuitry from ***I0*** pin to the corresponding nets (***I0_M1*** & ***I0_M2***) to connect to the MUXs? Or is there any other simple way? Also to be noted that input pins I0 - I3 can not be changed to any other input pins.

[image]

Comment: Are you asking a question about *electrical* compatibility (i.e. loading effects and fan-out) or *netlist* compatibility (i.e. cadence whining about naming)? For the latter case: If you're just connecting a pin to instance pins in your schematic, this shouldn't happen, so we'd need to know what you actually tried to do and why/how I0_M1 are labeled.

Comment: Thanks, I am asking about netlist compatibility. If the bottom part with mux 2 and feedback part would not be there, it would not be a problem. there are 4 buffers for different delays. So 4 selectable inputs (I0-I3) select the output from 4 buffers and feeds to the 4 inputs of the MUX. I0_M1 - I3_M1 and I0_M2 - I3_M2 are for inputs of the corresponding MUXs. I0_M1 - I3_M1 are net names. Suppose, when I connect I0 pin to I0_M1 and I0_M2, in the schematic editors those are shorted as those have 2 net names connected to 1 pin.

Comment: My instinct here would be to unlabel I0_M1 and I0_M2 - they're the same net, I0, which fans out. It seems like there's a reason why you can't do that though, but I'm not fully understanding it - please [edit] your post to add that (and your above comment)

Comment: Shouldn't there be at least 2 additional control inputs on each MUX module that selects the desired input channel?

Comment: Thanks. I know I ignored the control pins. But it is there in the MUX